# how to pass array values to javascript function from html onchange action?

Tags: javascript

I have a separate array like

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

I need to pass this array to JavaScript function as a parameter while `onChange` action is called.

can anyone give me a suggestion for that?

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have assigned that array into one variable and passed it like onchange('arrayname'). But it was not passed

Comment: What's `onchange` in this case? Could you please provide a [complete example](http://sscce.org/), preferably with http://jsfiddle.net/ demo?

Comment: Can you show some of your code???

Comment: Please show your code. Is that supposed to be a two-dimensional array, or...?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
var x1=[1,11,11];
var x2=[2,21,22];
var x3=[3,31,32];
var y=[x1,x2,x3];
onChange(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that's an option, but this is how it may work in jQuery:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="target" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#target').change(function() {
      var arr1 = [1,2,3];
      var arr2 = [1,2,3];
      var arr3 = [1,2,3];
      var arr = [arr1, arr2, arr3];
      //do whatever you want with it
      alert(arr);
});
});
```

I guess you could assign it to some hidden element (like input hidden) and then write some code that would read the arr value from it.

At least that's one of options - I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the function call in another anonymous function.

```
element.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    yourFunction(yourArray);
});
```