# How to pass an array from HTML to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which has multiple `<select>` drop-down boxes. I wish to pass the value in these drop-down boxes as an array to a JavaScript function.

Currently my code is like:

```
<select name="findByMaterial" onChange="filterFilms('Material',this.value)">
                    {% for film in all_films %}
                        <option value="{{film.f_material}}">{{film.f_material}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </select>
```

Where all_films is a variable from Django framework (Most probably you need not concern yourself with it).

What I want to do is that even if I have multiple selects with different names such as `findByMaterial` and `findByColor`, and I change the `findByColor`, then it should call the `filterFilms(String,Value)` JS function.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated a lot.

PS: This question is probably similar to [how to pass array values to JavaScript function from html onchange action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755771/how-to-pass-array-values-to-javascript-function-from-html-onchange-action), but it is definitely not what I am looking for.

**CLarification:**
I wish to create a filter. Thus I would want to be able to access the attribute of `color` as well as `material`.

Comment: So you want to attach the same event to multiple `<select>`s?

Comment: Yes, but passing different parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Online Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/thefourtheye/jRym8/

```
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title> Document </title>
        <script>
            function filterFilms(selectBox) {
                var displayArea = document.getElementById("displayArea");
                displayArea.innerHTML = selectBox.id + "," + selectBox.value + "," + selectBox.selectedIndex + "," +
                    selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].text;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select onchange="filterFilms(this);" id="films">
            <option value="film1">Film Text 1</option>
            <option value="film2">Film Text 2</option>
            <option value="film3">Film Text 3</option>
        </select>

        <select onchange="filterFilms(this);" id="colors">
            <option value="color1">Color 1</option>
            <option value="color2">Color 2</option>
            <option value="color3">Color 3</option>
        </select>

        <div id="displayArea"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can use the same function to do this. Pass the current element as the parameter. And

1. You can get the id of the select box clicked with `selectBox.id`
2. You can get the selected option's value with `selectBox.value`
3. You can get the selected option's index with `selectBox.selectedIndex`
4. You can get the selected option's text with `selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].text`

Comment: This answers the OP as asked, well done. I'd suggest going a step farther and separate the onChange events from the HTML and attach them from the script.

Comment: This seems good, but I really need to send the type of select that I am using. This is because sometimes the values of two different options of two different selects may match.

Comment: @SaketJain Please check my updated answer. You can get the id of the selected box using `selectBox.id`

Comment: @thefourtheye: Thanks! Any idea how I could access the attribute of `color` as well as `films` at the same time?

Comment: @SaketJain You can use `var colors = document.getElementById("color");` to get the colors select box and then you can access the attributes with the `colors` object.

Comment: @SaketJain You can gets the films also, in the same way.